# Regex in JavaScript whit multiple chars search like concat

Tags: javascript, regex, split, concatenation

I have a problem with regex splitting in javascript.
This is my text I want to split. It is in german language, but it is irrelevant, we can say it is just a dummy.

```
Gesamtwirtschaft, z. B. primärer, sekundärer, tertiärer Sektor, erwerbswirtschaftliche BetriebeEinstellungsgesprächTarifverträge (z. B. Entgelttarifvertrag, Manteltarifvertrag)EntgeltfortzahlungsgesetzBGB-KündigungBetriebsvereinbarungen bzw. Personalvertretung auf Grundlage des PersonalvertretungsgesetzesKündigungsschutzgesetzWirtschaftsorganisationenArbeitnehmervertretung, BetriebsratGeltungsbereichTarifverträge (z. B. Entgelttarifvertrag, Manteltarifvertrag)IT-Weiterbildung ergänzend zur Ausbildung in den IT-BerufenSozialabgaben: Krankenversicherung, Arbeitslosenversicherung, Rentenversicherung, PflegeversicherungLohnsteuer, KirchensteuerBundeselterngeld- und ElternzeitgesetzZiele von BetriebenZiele von BetriebenRentabilitätFusionKapitalgesellschaften, z. B. GmbH, AGMärkte und PreisbildungProduktpalette und MärkteVerjährungRechtsgeschäfteUnterschiedliche Lernorte, auf regionaler EbeneMöglichkeiten und Grenzen einer Existenzgründung, BusinessplanInternationale Spezialisierung, GlobalisierungMöglichkeiten und Grenzen der sozialen Marktwirtschaft
```

I use this regex : `/(?<=[a-z)])(?<![Gmb])(?=[A-Z])/` for splitting it by lookbehind if there is a lowercase immediately behind an uppercase letter or a closing bracket. It will not split if there was Gmb behind the uppercase letter. This is the array i get with this split:

```
"Array
(
    [0] => Gesamtwirtschaft, z. B. primärer, sekundärer, tertiärer Sektor, erwerbswirtschaftliche Betriebe
    [1] => Einstellungsgespräch
    [2] => Tarifverträge (z. B. Entgelttarifvertrag, Manteltarifvertrag)
    [3] => Entgeltfortzahlungsgesetz
    [4] => BGB-Kündigung
    [5] => Betriebsvereinbarungen bzw. Personalvertretung auf Grundlage des Personalvertretungsgesetzes
    [6] => Kündigungsschutzgesetz
    [7] => Wirtschaftsorganisationen
    [8] => Arbeitnehmervertretung, Betriebsrat
    [9] => Geltungsbereich
    [10] => Tarifverträge (z. B. Entgelttarifvertrag, Manteltarifvertrag)
    [11] => IT-Weiterbildung ergänzend zur Ausbildung in den IT-Berufen
    [12] => Sozialabgaben: Krankenversicherung, Arbeitslosenversicherung, Rentenversicherung, Pflegeversicherung
    [13] => Lohnsteuer, Kirchensteuer
    [14] => Bundeselterngeld- und Elternzeitgesetz
    [15] => Ziele von Betrieben
    [16] => Ziele von Betrieben
    [17] => Rentabilität
    [18] => Fusion
    [19] => Kapitalgesellschaften, z. B. GmbH, AGMärkte und Preisbildung
    [20] => Produktpalette und Märkte
    [21] => Verjährung
    [22] => Rechtsgeschäfte
    [23] => Unterschiedliche Lernorte, auf regionaler Ebene
    [24] => Möglichkeiten und Grenzen einer Existenzgründung, Businessplan
    [25] => Internationale Spezialisierung, Globalisierung
    [26] => Möglichkeiten und Grenzen der sozialen Marktwirtschaft
)
"
```

So my question is now how can I split arrayitem 19 after there is an AG in the lookbehind. The outcome should be this:

```
"Array
(
    [0] => Gesamtwirtschaft, z. B. primärer, sekundärer, tertiärer Sektor, erwerbswirtschaftliche Betriebe
    [1] => Einstellungsgespräch
    [2] => Tarifverträge (z. B. Entgelttarifvertrag, Manteltarifvertrag)
    [3] => Entgeltfortzahlungsgesetz
    [4] => BGB-Kündigung
    [5] => Betriebsvereinbarungen bzw. Personalvertretung auf Grundlage des Personalvertretungsgesetzes
    [6] => Kündigungsschutzgesetz
    [7] => Wirtschaftsorganisationen
    [8] => Arbeitnehmervertretung, Betriebsrat
    [9] => Geltungsbereich
    [10] => Tarifverträge (z. B. Entgelttarifvertrag, Manteltarifvertrag)
    [11] => IT-Weiterbildung ergänzend zur Ausbildung in den IT-Berufen
    [12] => Sozialabgaben: Krankenversicherung, Arbeitslosenversicherung, Rentenversicherung, Pflegeversicherung
    [13] => Lohnsteuer, Kirchensteuer
    [14] => Bundeselterngeld- und Elternzeitgesetz
    [15] => Ziele von Betrieben
    [16] => Ziele von Betrieben
    [17] => Rentabilität
    [18] => Fusion
    [19] => Kapitalgesellschaften, z. B. GmbH, AG
    [20] => Märkte und Preisbildung
    [21] => Produktpalette und Märkte
    [22] => Verjährung
    [23] => Rechtsgeschäfte
    [24] => Unterschiedliche Lernorte, auf regionaler Ebene
    [25] => Möglichkeiten und Grenzen einer Existenzgründung, Businessplan
    [26] => Internationale Spezialisierung, Globalisierung
    [27] => Möglichkeiten und Grenzen der sozialen Marktwirtschaft
)
"
```

I hope I did described everything understandable, and hope for answers! Thank you for your time!

Comment: place an optional character after the GMB lookahead.  `.?` _should_ work.

Comment: Isn't it having a latin character ä, this is not given in your regex rule

Comment: Did you mean `(?<!Gmb)` ? What happens if there is a `mGb` behind the capital letter .

Comment: @Randy Casburn Not sure what you mean with after the GMB lookahead. .? i tried /(?<=[a-z)])(?<!Gmb.?)(?=[A-Z])/ same issue

Comment: No, you should use `/(?<=[a-z)])(?<!Gmb)(?=[A-Z])/` to solve the issue with the character class. You also need to adjust this expression to account for the fact you want to also match when there are several uppercase letters followed with an uppercase + lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(?<=[\p{Ll})]|\p{Lu}(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll}))(?<!Gmb)(?=\p{Lu})/u
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g9S7ID/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=[\p{Ll})]|\p{Lu}(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll}))` - immediately to the left of the current location, there should be either a lowercase letter, `)`, or an uppercase letter that is followed with an uppercase letter and then a lowercase letter
- `(?<!Gmb)` - there must be no `Gmb` immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?=\p{Lu})` - there must be an uppercase letter immediately to the right of the current location.

Make sure you use the `/u` flag that enables Unicode category classes in JavaScript ECMAScript 2018+ compatible regex.